# In-text citation does not work

Tags: biblatex, citing

Consider the MWE below.

All the citations work, except for `england2002`. It only returns **england2002** but no citations.
How can this be solved?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, style=authoryear, uniquename=false]   {biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{renshaw1998,
title={A stochastic model underlying the chain-ladder technique},
author={Renshaw, Arthur E and Verrall, Richard J},
journal={British Actuarial Journal},
volume={4},
number={04},
pages={903--923},
year={1998},
publisher={Cambridge Univ Press}
}

@article{england2002,
title={Stochastic claims reserving in general insurance},
author={England, Peter D and Verrall, Richard J},
journal={British Actuarial Journal},
volume={8},
number={03},
pages={443--518},
year={2002},
publisher={Cambridge Univ Press}
}

@book{efron1994,
title={An introduction to the bootstrap},
author={Efron, Bradley and Tibshirani, Robert J},
year={1994},
publisher={CRC press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}[a4paper,12pt]

I cite  \citet{renshaw1998} and \citet{england2002} and \citet{efron1994}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. Try to put the question **out** from the MWE.

2. What is the purpose the environment `filecontents`?

3. Why you repeat the class options after open the `document` environment?

Comment: The MWE works absolutely fine here, if I add `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` and ignore the spurious `[a4paper,12pt]`. Did you run `pdflatex <document>`, `biber <document>`, `pdflatex <document>`? Were there any errors/warnings issued by Biber?

Comment: The code produces errors when pasted in Overleaf.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of your code, with some corrections.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
%!!! changed, use of biblatex moved after filecontents
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib}    %!!! changed, jobname removed
@article{renshaw1998,
title={A stochastic model underlying the chain-ladder technique},
author={Renshaw, Arthur E and Verrall, Richard J},
journal={British Actuarial Journal},
volume={4},
number={04},
pages={903--923},
year={1998},
publisher={Cambridge Univ Press}
}

@article{england2002,
title={Stochastic claims reserving in general insurance},
author={England, Peter D and Verrall, Richard J},
journal={British Actuarial Journal},
volume={8},
number={03},
pages={443--518},
year={2002},
publisher={Cambridge Univ Press}
}

@book{efron1994,
title={An introduction to the bootstrap},
author={Efron, Bradley and Tibshirani, Robert J},
year={1994},
publisher={CRC press}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,citestyle=alphabetic,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}    %!!! changed and moved here
\addbibresource{bib}    %!!! new, declearation inserted
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{citetitle}{#1}    %!!! new, optional
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1}    %!!! new, optional

\begin{document}    %!!! changed, declarion already handled in documentclass

I cite \cite{renshaw1998} and \cite{england2002} and \cite{efron1994}        %!!! changed

% bibliography    %!!! new, optional
\printbibliography    %!!! new, optional
\end{document}
```

See also in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/2594441fqkvmc#/6828650/). The link to Overleaf - an online TeX environment - may come handy to reproduce the MWE.

Comment: \DeclareFieldFormat[inbook] is optional

Comment: Please explain your corrections and mark them in your code, for example by '%!!! changed' or ... Suppose the reader is a beginner and not able to localize or understand your changes ... And why the link to overleaf?